# 2 functions with the same name

Tags: less

I found the following example on the [less-website](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions). These are commands to create a shadow. I'm wondering which one is called first, as the have the same function name. Why do they have the same name?

```
@base: #f938ab;

.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  -moz-box-shadow:    @style @c;
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
}

.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
```

Comment: See [Pattern Matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) and [Mixin Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less allows you to make two mixins (they are not really functions) with the same name (or 3, 4, 5...). If they both match parameters called, they will both do their effects in order of the mixin definition.

In this case, these two would NOT be called at the same time because of the conditional `when` statement on them that filters out the passed in values. If the second parameter is a color, the first mixin is called. If the second value is a number, the second mixin is called.

In this case, the second mixin is using the first mixin within itself. So if the second one is called by passing a number, it defaults the color to black, but adds an opacity level based off the number. It then calls the first mixin to actually output the final property values with the defined black color.

In generally, it is allowing flexibility and short cuts for doing the mixin call with the second mixin.